# How to reference a Excel Worksheet within a function

Tags: ms-access, excel, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to call a excel work sheet to a function however i get an error `438 "OBJECT DOESN'T SUPPORT THIS PROPERTY OR METHOD"`

The code below makes the call to applyStyle1

```
Dim wkb7 As Excel.Workbook
Set wkb7 = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(strDir&"\NEXTDAY.xls")
wkb7.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Set wks7 = wkb.Sheets.Add

applyStyle1 (wks7)
```

The function:

```
Function applyStyle1(wksContainer As Excel.Worksheet)
     With wksContainer
              ......
     End With
End Function
```

This code works when the function call is replaced with the code within the function, however since it is called multiple times i require it to be in a function rather duplicating the code. Thank you for your time, pleas advise me if you require a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **First Problem**

The line `strDir&"\NEXTDAY.xls"` should be `strDir & "\NEXTDAY.xls"`. There should be a space before and after the `&` sign.

> **Second Problem**

You have declared `wkb7` but are using `wkb` in `Set wks7 = wkb.Sheets.Add`. I would recommend using `Option Explicit`

> **Third Problem**

Change the line as suggested by @MarkHone `Set wks7 = wkb.Sheets.Add` to

```
Set wks7 = wkb7.Worksheets.Add
```

> **Fourth Problem (Your Actual Problem!)**

`applyStyle1` is a function which needs to return something. If you are not returning anything then Use a `Sub` instead.

For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wkb7 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks7 As Excel.Worksheet

    Set wkb7 = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open(strDir & "\NEXTDAY.xls")
    wkb7.ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy

    Set wks7 = wkb7.Worksheets.Add

    applyStyle1 wks7
End Sub

Sub applyStyle1(wksContainer As Excel.Worksheet)
    With wksContainer

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Good and detailed answer and I concur Option Explicit is recommended.  I'm not sure why you split the 5th line into two statements though?

Comment: @MarkHone: Sorry i was testing something and forgot to update that. I did mention the correct one in the fourth problem though :)

Comment: Oh yes, so you did; no complaints then :-)

Comment: Thank you @SiddharthRout for the fast reply i am testing the code however get and error on "applyStyle1 wks7"  the error states that the ByRef argument type mismatch, but in the code both are referenced as Excel.Worksheet.

Comment: @KSM: Did you declare `Dim wks7 As Excel.Worksheet` I don't see that in your original code?

Comment: Yes it was coded as so   
 Dim wks, wks2, wks3, wks4, wks5, wks6, wks7 As Excel.Worksheet

Comment: @KSM: Unlike vb.net, in VBA you have to explicitly declare all variables. `wks, wks2, wks3, wks4, wks5, wks6` will be declared as `Variants`. Change that line to `Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet, wks2 As Excel.Worksheet, wks3 As Excel.Worksheet, wks4 As Excel.Worksheet, wks5 As Excel.Worksheet, wks6 As Excel.Worksheet, wks7 As Excel.Worksheet`

Comment: Excellent stuff thank you everything works fine, appreciate the help       
@SiddharthRout

Answer (score 3):

Please try changing your 5th line from:

```
Set wks7 = wkb.Sheets.Add
```

to:

```
Set wks7 = wkb.Worksheets.Add
```

Sheets will include all sheets within the workbook, including chart sheets.